# English and Arabic Language Switching in Single BB 10 Cascades

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have developed a BB 10 Application where I need to provide English and Arabic Language Switching.Now App is working good in English,when the user selects Arabic Language,Total Application is need to be converted into Arabic Language. My App Contains more than 18 Qmls.
each Qml has more than 10 containers.

If it is  English, we provide containers Orientation from LeftToRight,If it is Arabic RightToLeft and Label Alignments etc.I have tried to change the Orientation based on User Selection.But I think, it is not a good method to do so.

now my App should switch b/w English and Arabic Languages.What is the best way to do it?

Guide me,
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going on right way...

You can save current language in persistant storage and use this value in all QML.

Get current language from persistant storage in every QML and applied orientation according to language..

Some days ago I given you [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18981111/624069). Just follow this for all QML..